# Elastic Beanstalk structured logs not parsed by CloudWatch Log Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an elastic beanstalk application that logs output to console in JSON format. However, in Log Insights, the fields are not discoverable. I noticed that CloudWatch seems to prefix every log line like

```
Dec  4 21:50:18 ip-123-23-23-123 web: { ...JSON here... }
```

Going directly to the log group, I can query the logs with a query like `{ $.StatusCode >= 500 }`, but in Log Insights it doesn't seem to parse the JSON and does not discover fields. How do I get Log Insights to discover fields and/or parse my json to make queries easier?